# Aerospike user not found when running as nonroot

Tags: docker, aerospike, aerospike-loader

I am using community edition aerospike docker image.
Our k8s cluster does not allow running containers as root. hence i started following [this](https://docs.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/non_root/index.html) doc for running as non root.

But when run the image i am getting below error

```
link eth0 state up
link eth0 state up in 0
Dec 02 2021 10:15:12 GMT: CRITICAL (config): (cfg.c:2168) line 6 :: user not found: 8888
Dec 02 2021 10:15:12 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c:166) SIGINT received, shutting down Aerospike Community Edition build 5.6.0.7 os debian10
Dec 02 2021 10:15:12 GMT: WARNING (as): (signal.c:169) startup was not complete, exiting immediately
```

I am having below config in my aerospike conf

```
    service {
      user 8888
      group 8888
      paxos-single-replica-limit 1 # Number of nodes where the replica count is automatically reduced to 1.
      pidfile /var/run/aerospike/asd.pid
      # service-threads 6 # cpu x 5 in 4.7
      # transaction-queues 6 # obsolete in 4.7
      # transaction-threads-per-queue 4 # obsolete in 4.7
      proto-fd-max 15000
      }
```

and below is my k8s config

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: aerospike
  labels:
    app: aerospike
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 0%
      maxUnavailable: 100%
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: aerospike
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: aerospike
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: aerospikeconfig
      containers:
        - name: aerospike-container
          image: aerospikeimage
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/aerospike/
              name: config-volume
          env:
            - name: NAMESPACE
              value: "bar"
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 8888
            runAsGroup: 8888
            runAsNonRoot: true
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 1Gi
              cpu: 1
            limits:
              memory: 1Gi
              cpu: 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is not Kubernetes related but just aerospike
You are using uid/gid

```
user 8888
group 8888
```

Could you try using username/groupname

```
service {
      user aerospike
      group aerospike
      paxos-single-replica-limit 1 # Number of nodes where the replica count is automatically reduced to 1.
      pidfile /var/run/aerospike/asd.pid
      # service-threads 6 # cpu x 5 in 4.7
      # transaction-queues 6 # obsolete in 4.7
      # transaction-threads-per-queue 4 # obsolete in 4.7
      proto-fd-max 15000
      }
```

Comment: kubernates does not allow non integer users right?

Comment: Aren't you configuring them in the aerospike conf? It is in that config file that you need username and group name rather than uid and GID

Comment: thanks @joem, it works. can you please update the answer and make it more verbose?